# ending transaction with Yii::app()->end

Tags: yii, yii2

yii 1

Will Mysql Innodb transaction also end after Yii::app()->end() ? 
Here based on model validation an error is being returned to javascript :

```
    begin transaction

    if (!$model->save()) {
       echo CJSON::encode(array(
                                "error"=>true,
                                "errorDetails" => $model->getErrors(),
                                "code"=>"500"
                    ));
       Yii::app()->end();
    }

   end transaction
```

Can we find active transactions for Yii::app() and end live transaction in above case since it will otherwise leave transaction open

```
Yii::app()->onEndRequest = function($event){
    //Find active transaction for current request and db and rollback 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved it in index.php

```
$app = Yii::createWebApplication($config);


Yii::app()->onEndRequest = function($event){
    if(!is_null(Yii::app()->db->getCurrentTransaction())) {     
        Yii::app()->db->getCurrentTransaction()->rollback();
    }
};

$app->run();
```